# AIML Bot Encoding Issue - Cyrillic Recognition Failure

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, artificial-intelligence, aiml

## Problem Overview

Since I've had a task to create a chattering bot I've used an AIML library to perform a simple conversation between the user and the computer. I had configuration files and just one aiml file called 'Bank'. Everything worked extremely well, while I was querying on English. But the main purpose was to make a bot speak Russian. So, from that moment I've been facing an encoding problem. Practically when I type something in cyrillic format, the programm returs null as an output. I tried to change the xml encoding to utf-8, alter console encoding, decompile that dll library seeking for the clue of the problem. But unfortunately nothing really works.

## Code

Bot Class:

```
class Acutus
{

private Bot bot;
private User user;

public Acutus()
{
    bot = new Bot();
    user = new User("userID", bot);
}

public void Initialize()
{
    bot.loadSettings();
    bot.isAcceptingUserInput = false;
    bot.loadAIMLFromFiles();
    bot.isAcceptingUserInput = true;
}

public String GetOutput(String input)
{
    Request r = new Request(input, user, bot);
    Result result = bot.Chat(r);
    return result.Output;
}

}
```

Main.cs:

```
    bool isSimulating = true;

    Acutus acutus = new Acutus();
    acutus.Initialize();

    while (isSimulating)
    {
        String input = Console.ReadLine();
        isSimulating = input == String.Empty ? false : true;
        String output = acutus.GetOutput(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

Settings.xmls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <item name="aimldirectory" value="aiml"/>
  <item name="configdirectory" value="config"/>
  <item name="logdirectory" value="logs"/>
  <item name="splittersfile" value="Splitters.xml"/>
  <item name="maxlogbuffersize" value="64"/>
  <item name="person2substitutionsfile" value="Person2Substitutions.xml"/>
  <item name="personsubstitutionsfile" value="PersonSubstitutions.xml"/>
  <item name="gendersubstitutionsfile" value="GenderSubstitutions.xml"/>
  <item name="defaultpredicates" value="DefaultPredicates.xml"/>
  <item name="substitutionsfile" value="Substitutions.xml"/>
  <item name="notacceptinguserinputmessage" value="This bot is currently set to not accept user input."/>
  <item name="stripperregex" value="[^0-9a-zA-Z]"/>
</root>
```

Bank.aiml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml>
    <category>
        <pattern>*</pattern>
        <template>
            <random>
                <li>тест</li>
            </random>
        </template>
    </category>
</aiml>
```

Comment: the problem is solved.

Comment: how can you solve this problem?

Comment: @SadeghAlavizadeh I just added cyrillic symbols to the regular expression pattern in settings :) Or you can decompile the dll library and change the pattern internally